# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: java, sql-server

Iam getting a error in String qquery when i run the code `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`  my sql qquery is running well in sqlserver he minus the products quantity .Any idea ? ty

error log

```
at mylogin.Basket.makesales(Basket.java:160)
    at mylogin.Basket.ReceiptActionPerformed(Basket.java:455)
    at mylogin.Basket.access$100(Basket.java:23)
```

Here is my code

```
      public void  executeSQLQuery (String query,String message) {
        Connection con =getConnection();
        Statement st;
        try{
            st =con.createStatement();
            if((st.executeUpdate(query))==1)
            {
               con.commit(); 

               DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable_ProSales.getModel();
                model.setRowCount(0);
               show_Basket_in_Jtable();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data "+message+" Succefully");
            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data Not "+message+ "Error");
            }

                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

action button

```
 private void ReceiptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        String query= "INSERT INTO Sales (Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity,Pro_Price ) SELECT Pro_Id,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity ,Pro_Price FROM Receipt";
    executeSQLQuery(query,"Inserted");
  String qquery= " UPDATE Products SET Pro_Quantity= Products.Pro_Quantity - Receipt.Sales_Quantity FROM Products INNER JOIN Receipt ON Products.Pro_Id = Receipt.Pro_Id)" ; 
       executeSQLQuery(qquery,"updated");
    }
```

Comment: You have a closing parenthesis in your query, but no opening one.

Comment: Ty very much  finally is running

Comment: Please close this question if your problem is resolved.

Comment: how i can close the post ?

Comment: @George Kontonikolaou - you can always delete it, at least as long as there is no upvoted answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 private void ReceiptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        String query= "INSERT INTO Sales (Pro_Id ,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity,Pro_Price ) SELECT Pro_Id,Pro_Name,Sales_Quantity ,Pro_Price FROM Receipt";
    executeSQLQuery(query,"Inserted");
  String qquery= " UPDATE Products SET Pro_Quantity= Products.Pro_Quantity - Receipt.Sales_Quantity FROM Products INNER JOIN Receipt ON Products.Pro_Id = Receipt.Pro_Id" ; 
       executeSQLQuery(qquery,"updated");
    }
```